# Facebook JS SDK -Access Tokens unable to post actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I use the code below nothing happens,I am unable to understand why this is so

```
function graphStreamPublish(){
var passString = '?[OBJECT]=http://entrancesuccess.net&access_token=' + accesstoken;

 FB.api('/me/[APPNAMESPACE]:[ACTION]' + passString,'post', 
            function(response) {
                showLoader(false);

                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
        }
```

but, when I just simply copy-paste the Access Token(YTWYDGFXVVZG456AVGAFV45HGCZXHGFACGFCGFXDG546FXGFXJGFXGFXGXFJXGFXG) in the variable "passString" everything works fine and actions are published on user activity on facebook.

Example:

```
  function graphStreamPublish(){
var passString = '?[OBJECT]=http://entrancesuccess.net&access_token=YTWYDGFXVVZG456AVGAFV45HGCZXHGFACGFCGFXDG546FXGFXJGFXGFXGXFJXGFXG';
```

The rest of the code is below(if required):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', //change the appId to your appId
                status: true, 
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true});

           showLoader(true);

           function updateButton(response) {
                button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');

                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //user is already logged in and connected
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                        login(response, info);
                    });

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            logout(response);
                        });
                    };
                } else {
                    //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                    button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                    button.onclick = function() {
                        showLoader(true);
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                    login(response, info);
                                });    
                            } else {
                                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                showLoader(false);
                            }
                        }, {scope:'publish_stream,public_action'});     
                    }
                }
            }

            // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol 
                + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());


        function login(response, info){
            if (response.authResponse) {
                 var accessToken                                 =            response.authResponse.accessToken;

                userInfo.innerHTML                             = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id + '/picture">' + info.name
                                                                 + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;
                button.innerHTML                               = 'Logout';
                showLoader(false);
                document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        function logout(response){
            userInfo.innerHTML                             =   "";
            document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML     =   "";
            document.getElementById('other').style.display =   "none";
            showLoader(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d say there is no variable `accesstoken` in your function `graphStreamPublish`.

You’re using the `var` keyword in the function `login`, which makes it a *local* variable – so it’s contents are thrown away once that function is done.

You could do the assignment without `var`, then it’d be a *global* variable, and `graphStreamPublish` should be able to access it.

But normally you should not need to pass the access token explicitly at all, because the JS SDK is perfectly capable of passing it by itself in the background, without any need for you to pass it around actively by yourself.